# What does "currying allows abstraction over arity" mean?

Tags: haskell, currying

Looking for benefits of currying in functional programming in Javascript I came across the following Haskell example:

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

It is said that the type variable `c` can be a function type so that this function works on some prefix of its argument's parameter list. I don't know Haskell but this is clearly just function composition. What does abstraction over arity mean in this context and in which way it is an advantage? Can someone briefly explain it to me by using a Javascript example?

Comment: In javascript you'd have something similar to: `function compose(f, g) {function h(x) {return f(g(x))}; return h;}`.  Note how `h` has one argument. To compose functions with different number of arguments you'd have to write multiple `compose` functions. In Haskell you get that for free. In python you could do: `def compose(f, g): return lambda x, *args: f(g(x), *args)` to obtain the same effect. No idea if this can be done in javascript.

Comment: @Bakuriu, it can be done in JavaScript (its `function` keyword is essentially a lambda form). The syntactic overhead of writing and using such functions is prohibitive. And dealing with the inevitable arity errors without static typing is painful. And I think you'll likely pay a hefty efficiency price to boot.

Comment: @dfeuer @Bakuriu So it just means that currying allows composing of n-ary functions? `const comp = f => g => x => f(g(x)); const comp2 = comp(comp)(comp);
const add = x => y => x + y; comp2(add)(add)(1)(2)(3);`

Comment: Ah, it seems the syntactic overhead has been reduced! Still, not having static types makes this sort of thing a bit tricky to get right. And a *culture* of defining multi-argument functions to take comma-separated style tends to make generic combinators annoying to use in practice, with lots of `curry`/`uncurry` sorts of noise.

Comment: @dfeuer Yeah, therefore each function has to go through dozens of unit tests. That is the price to be paid for a missing type system/compiler.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, this *is* just function composition. The point they're making is that `(.)` can be used at any of these types (among others), the first of which is the most general:

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
(.) :: (b -> c -> d) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c -> d
(.) :: (b -> c -> d -> e) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c -> d -> e
...
```

Here's a brain teaser for you. What's the type of `(.) . (.)`, the composition of the composition function with itself?

The composition function may not actually be the most enlightening example. If you study Haskell some more, you'll encounter others, such as the "applicative style" of combining results of actions. For instance,

```
getLine
```

reads a line from standard input.

```
(,) <$> getLine <*> getLine
```

reads two and bundles them up in a pair.

```
(,,) <$> getLine <*> getLine <*> getLine
```

reads three and bundles them in a triple. This all works because the operators are left-associative and don't care that there are functions all about. The last example, for instance, is equivalent to

```
(((,,) <$> getLine) <*> getLine) <*> getLine
```

It maps `(,,)` over the `getLine` action, yielding an action that reads a line and produces a function of two arguments. That action is applies to `getLine`, yielding an action that reads two lines and produces a function of one argument. Finally, that's applied to `getLine`, yielding an action that reads three lines and produces a triple.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's only one type in Javascript. So I guess `(.) . (.)` would be something like `(a -> a) -> (a -> a -> a) -> a -> a -> a`. That's fun!

Comment: @IvenMarquardt, well yes, Javascript is "unityped" or "dynamically typed" or "untyped", so you could just say `(.) :: JavascriptValue`, but that wouldn't be too useful! It's very often valuable, when working in a language like Javascript, to maintain some sort of type discipline regardless, documenting values as having "types" that are the most general they're supposed to work for. In Haskell, `(.) . (.)` has type `(c -> d) -> (a -> b -> c) -> a -> b -> d`, and so I'd view `compose (compose) (compose)` in JS as having that notional type as well.

Comment: In Javascript: Given is `comp :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c`. By currying, `(b -> c)` (which is evaluated last due to the right associativity) may be of arbitrary arity, because `c` can be a function type. That's abstraction over arity. This is not true for `(a -> b)` (which is evaluated first). We need discrete `compN` functions for each arity greater than one: `comp2 = comp(comp)(comp)`, `comp3 = comp(comp)(comp(comp)(comp))`, ...